# Find my Mac: "Online, no location available"

Tags: macos, mac, icloud, find-my-iphone, find-my-mac

I'm testing the "find my Mac" feature at icloud.com and one of my Macs can't be found. The site reports "Online, no location available".

I've looked around a bit including at Apple's [TS 4006](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4006), which includes troubleshooting for this situation. So I'll mention that:

- Find My Mac is enabled on the Mac in System Preferences --> iCloud.
- The date and time zone on the Mac are correct.
- The Mac is connected to the internet via Wifi. Other Macs on the same Wifi network are found, so it doesn't appear to be a problem with Wifi location.
- Location Services is enabled in System Preferences --> Security & Privacy --> Privacy
- I am in the USA, where this feature should work (and as mentioned, *does* work for other Macs on the same network).
- I'm logged in to the same iCloud account on multiple Macs, but only the one Mac is not found.

Also, though not specifically mentioned in TS 4006 or on other sites that I've seen:

- The Mac does not have a firewall enabled
- The "Play Sound" feature of Find my Mac works. If I click on this at icloud.com, a loud annoying noise plays on the affected Mac.
- The affected Mac is able to determine its own location well enough to set the time zone automatically and identify the city I'm in.
- Web sites that ask for my location on the Mac (e.g. Foursquare) get the correct location.

Rebooting the Mac **does not have any effect** on any of this.

The Mac is a 2012 MacBook Air, running Mac OS X 10.8.5, with all current updates applied.

Comment: Hi... you've done most of the things I can think of to isolate this already, so I'm grabbing at straws.  1) Does anything show in Console.app on the MacBook Air when you look for that machine at iCloud.com?  2) If you take the MacBook Air to another WiFi network (friend's house, coffee shop...), is the behaviour the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just waited a while, and it started working. There's no indication of why it wasn't working at one point but then started working later on. That's kind of concerning, because I wonder how reliable the system is. But there doesn't seem to be any fix beyond "wait it out".

Answer (score 9):

Turning on Wi-Fi did the trick for me.

My MacPro's location wasn't showing up.  It is connected to the Wi-Fi router via ethernet.  I turned on Wi-Fi (to the same router), and my MacPro's location now shows up in icloud.com under the Find My iPhone pages.

Answer (score 0):

FYI:
+1 turned WiFi on, not connected to any WiFi network, no auto-join to any wifi, and suddenly, the location is now working in iCloud 'find my' service correctly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/319868)